# A Taylor Expansion of a Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, taylor-expansion

As part of a binomial model of a stochastic process, my professor claims that the Taylor Expansion of:
$$x\pm = 1 \pm (e^{\sigma^{2}h} - 1)^{1/2}$$

is: $$x = 1 \pm \sigma \sqrt h + O(h^{3/2}) $$

Here is my attempt at a proof using just the standard properties of series and the expansion of $e^x$ as a start:
$$e^{x} = 1 + x + x^{2}/2! + x^{3}/3! + ...$$
$$e^{\sigma^{2}h} = 1 + \sigma^{2} h + (\sigma^{2}h)^{2}/ 2! + (\sigma^{2}h)^{3}/3! + ... $$
$$(e^{\sigma^{2}h} -1 )^{1/2}= \sigma \sqrt{h} + \sigma^{2}h \sqrt{1/2} + (\sigma^{2}h)^{3/2} \sqrt{1/6} + ... $$
$$1 \pm (e^{\sigma^{2}h} -1 )^{1/2}= 1 \pm \sigma \sqrt{h} + \sigma^{2}h \sqrt{1/2} + (\sigma^{2}h)^{3/2} \sqrt{1/6} + ... $$

Which is close but I'm still stuck with the $\sigma^2 h$ term. Anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: First detail: you forgot the $1$ in the expansion of $e^{\sigma^2 h}$.

Comment: Thanks, will update the question

Comment: The actual statement isn't correct as written, the leading order term should be $1$.

Comment: Should be fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in the third step you take: $\sqrt{a+b} \neq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$. You should use the expansion of $\sqrt{1+u}$ when $u\to 0$, writing
$$
\sqrt{e^{\sigma^2h}-1} =  \sqrt{\sigma^2h + \frac{\sigma^4h^2}{2!} + o(h^2)}
=  \sqrt{\sigma^2h}\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sigma^2h}{2!} + o(h)}
$$
and expanding the right factor as mentioned above.

Comment: I assume this is the direction you are trying to point me in?$$e^{x} = 1 + x + x^{2}/2! + x^{3}/3! + ...$$
$$e^{\sigma^{2}h} = 1 + \sigma^{2} h + (\sigma^{2}h)^{2}/ 2! + (\sigma^{2}h)^{3}/3! + ... $$
$$(e^{\sigma^{2}h} -1 )^{1/2}= \sqrt{\sigma^2 h + (\sigma^{2}h)^2/2! + (\sigma^{2}h)^{3}/3! + ... }$$
$$(e^{\sigma^{2}h} -1 )^{1/2}= \sqrt{\sigma^2 h} \sqrt{1 + \sigma^2 h / 2! + O(h) + ... }$$
But because 
$$ \sqrt{1+x} = 1 + x/2 - x^2/8 + x^3/16 + ...$$
Then
$$(e^{\sigma^{2}h} -1 )^{1/2}=  (\sigma^{2}h)^{1/2} (1 + \sigma^{2}h / 4 - ...)$$

Comment: $$(e^{\sigma^{2}h} -1 )^{1/2}=  (\sigma^{2}h)^{1/2} + (\sigma^{2}h)^{3/2} / 4$$

Comment: @NickWilton Yes -- although you may want to put a $o()$ or $O()$ for the conclusion -- it is not a strict equality otherwise.